# How to use OAuth2.0 token with Google Translate

Tags: api, oauth, google-api, google-translate

According to the Google Translate API docs, https://cloud.google.com/translate/v2/using_rest, you can authenticate with OAuth 2.0 or an API key.

All of the examples online I've seen simply provide an API key.

Do you know how to run a Google Translate API call with an OAuth 2.0 access token?

Comment: What language are you developing in? The Oauth 2.0 flow using the Java Client Library is at https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2.

Comment: @Adam I'm using Python. I used the OAuth 2.0 flow using the Python Client Library and I receive an error saying I'm out of unauthenticated requests...

Comment: "Out of unauthenticated requests"? Could you post the exact response?

Comment: @Adam <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?q=flower&q=car&source=en&alt=json&target=fr returned "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.">